# How to ShowDialog two windows sequentially with APP.xaml Startup function

Tags: c#, wpf, startup, multi-window

```
private void AppToStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{           
    var startUpWindow=new StartUpWindow();
    startUpWindow.ShowDialog();
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

I have wrote these commands to `ShowDialog` `MainWindow` after `StartUpWindow`.
But when I close the `StartUpWindow` instance, the entire application closes.
What's wrong with my code?
If there is a better way to doing what I want instead of creating an instance and calling his `ShowDialog` method please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i added `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` in APP.xaml properties , my app closing with `Application.Current.Shutdown();` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by checking your `Application.ShutdownMode` property to see what it is set to. It can be found in `App.xaml`.

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A ShutdownMode of OnMainWindowClose causes Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) to implicitly call Shutdown when the MainWindow closes, even if other windows are currently open.